# how do I solve the equation with double sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

How do I solve the following optimization problem?

$$\min_{c}\  \sum_{i=1}^{P} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left[ (q_{n}^{i} - c_n)^2 - (g^i)^2 \right]^2.$$

what are the different options available to achieve the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, notice that the objective function splits into $N$ terms involving disjoint optimization variables. It therefore suffices to minimize each term individually:
$$\min_{c_n}\ \sum_{i=1}^P \left[(q^i_n-c_n)^2-(g^i)^2\right]^2.$$
This objective function is a quartic polynomial in one variable $(c_n)$ that clearly attains its global minimum. Its derivative is
$$\sum_{i=1}^P -4\left[(q^i_n-c_n)^2-(g^i)^2\right](q_n^i-c_n)$$
which is cubic. Use your favorite polynomial root-finding method (e.g. Jenkins-Traub) to solve for the real roots of the cubic (there will be one or three of them), and plug them into the above objective function to test for which one is the global minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...and your answer is helpful.....
But, I forget to mention in the problem that the term $g^i$ is also unknown. I differentiate the function w.r.to $g^i$ and got,
$ g^i = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} (q_{n}^{i} - c_n)^2}$.

I tried to use the above relation in the derivative you mentioned. 
Then splitting into N terms is kind of problem with double loop.
Can you suggest any ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: @akum I don't see how you got that expression for $g^i$, as your objective function is also quartic in $g^i$. In any case, if you want to so dramatically change the parameters of the question, you should post a new question. At some point you'll just need to use Newton's method to solve the (nonlinear, non-convex) optimization problem.